# Color network nodes according to attribute using igraph in R while simultaneously displaying Girvan Newman communities

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, vertices

I am trying to display a social network with Girvan Newman communities using igraph in R. I additionally want to distinguish the nodes according to attribute data (e.g., male nodes blue, female nodes pink). I know how to do this in a typical graph, but I'm having trouble executing this successfully while using the Girvan Newman algorithm. Here is my code so far:

```
    fgn = edge.betweenness.community (fmg, directed = TRUE, edge.betweenness = TRUE, merges = TRUE, bridges = TRUE, modularity = TRUE, membership = TRUE)

    plot(fgn,fmg)
```

If I were simply plotting the network without employing the Girvan Newman algorithm, I would distinguish the nodes in this way:

```
    V(fmg)[V(fmg)$gender== 1]$color <- "dodgerblue"
    V(fmg)[V(fmg)$gender== 2]$color <- "pink"
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to distinguish the nodes appropriately while using the algorithm, though I've tried. Any specific advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

- Answer to your question: [sixhat](http://www.sixhat.net/finding-communities-in-networks-with-r-and-igraph.html)
- Similar question in StackOverFlow (It's not exactly your question):
  [correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999877/correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph)