# Getting "supplied color is neither numeric nor character" error when trying to color vertices in R's igraph

Tags: r, visualization, igraph

I am trying to color vertices in a graph plot that I'm doing in R. The vertex list consists of nodes with an attribute `value` that is either set to "l" or "r".  In order to color code these vertices, I did the following:

```
V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$value == "l", "lightblue", "red")
```

This seems to work, but when I plot the graph like so:

```
plot(g, vertex.label=NA)
```

I get a message:

> There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

And when I inspect the errors they all read:

> "supplied color is neither numeric or character"

This confuses me as the colors seem to be characters since they are surrounded by quotes. Also this method of setting the colors came from an answer on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999877/correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph).

Can anyone clarify for me what might be going on here.

Comment: See my anwer-but-not-an-answer example below. There has to be something else going on in your environment. Can you post your `sessionInfo()` and, perhaps, the output of `dput(g)`?

Comment: result of sessioninfo here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ezmiller/public/images/Projectspolbooks-graph_-_RStudio_2016-08-17_13-36-00.png

Comment: dput result for a subgraph that of `g`: http://hastebin.com/uzebucegoj.md

Comment: You somehow managed to get `$color` to be a `list` vs a character vector. That had to have happened somewhere else in your code.

Comment: is there a way to change that? before I was trying to set the color by creating a kind of hash with a list: `colrs <- list(l = "lightblue", c = "red")`. then I did `v(sub)$color <- colr[V(sub)$value]`

Comment: try to get a minimal, representative, reproducible question posted and folks might be able to help then.