# how to color the nodes and labels in ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph

How to specify the color of the edge in ggraph plot like this

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
df_school = highschool %>% mutate(yr=ifelse(year%%2==0,'purple','blue'))
graph = df_school %>% graph_from_data_frame()
V(graph)$node_label = names(V(graph))
ggraph(graph, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc(aes(colour = factor(year))) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label=node_label), alpha=0.2) + 
  scale_edge_colour_identity()
```

Here only the edge is colored, but I don't know how to code the nodes or labels, or make the label background semi-transparent. Wondering if anyone can help.

Comment: It's missing a part of your code, where you define `graph` (and you're using dplyr without mentioning it). However you can use the `alpha` in  `geom_node_label()` to make the labels background transparent. To color the nodes, you need to specify the color and the nodes, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999877/correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph).

Answer (score 0):

You control the nodes and node labels separately. The prefix is `geom_node_` -- there are many options. The following code produces this plot.

```
ggraph(graph, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc(aes(colour = factor(year))) + 
  geom_node_point(size = 8)+ # add nodes
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), # add node labels
                 colour = 'white')+
  coord_equal()
```

[image]