# How to color specific nodes in the bipartite graph?

Tags: igraph, bipartite

I have plotted a bipartite graph using igraph. I want to color specific nodes of my interest with different colors.

The code which i have used is

bmat=as.matrix(read.csv(file = "/home/tejaswini/Desktop/Butterflyplantdata.csv" , sep = "\t", header=T, row.names=1))

bmat

library(igraph)
bg=graph_from_incidence_matrix(bmat)
bg

V(bg)$type #Display the vertex types. They are "FALSE" or "TRUE"

library(bipartite)
plotweb(bmat) #the base function for bipartite network plot

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's an igraph-pure solution:

```
library(igraph)

anemonefish <- matrix(# http://www.ecologia.ib.usp.br/iwdb/data/anemone_fish/anemonefish.txt
    c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    nrow = 26, byrow = TRUE)

g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(anemonefish)

plot(g, vertex.label = "", vertex.color = V(g)$type + 1, layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

That's if you want to color the nodes by type. If you want some other method of assigning colors, the easiest thing to do is make [a node attribute called `color`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999877/correctly-color-vertices-in-r-igraph):

```
palette("Tableau 10")
V(g)$color <- sample(1:length(palette()), vcount(g), replace = TRUE)

plot(g, vertex.label = "", layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```